# Excessive number of api calls for refresh token

Tags: authentication, jwt, axios

After reading through multiple JWT refresh token tutorials I am still unclear on how the flow of API calls is supposed to work.

Here is my understanding:

1) Client is in posession of access token and refresh token. It submits the access token to `api/getCustomerData`.

2) Let's say the access token is expired. Server responds with a `401`.

3) Client responds to the `401` request with the refresh token to `api/token`.

4) Server responds with new access token since the refresh token is still valid.

5) Client then makes a new request to `api/getCustomerData` with the new access token.

My impression is that this is an excessive number of API calls, but I am not seeing any tutorial that clarifies a way to do this more efficiently. As it stands it seems like if I am following this pattern, each API request will look like this:

```
    const getCustomers = async () => {
    const config = {
        data: body,
        withCredentials: true,
        method: 'POST' as 'POST',
    }
    await axios(address + '/api/getCustomerData', config)
        .then((response) => {
            ...
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            const response = error.response;
            if (response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    if (!failcount){
                       failcount++;
                       getCustomers();
                    }
                    else {
                       history.push('/login')
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pre-emptively get a new access token using a refresh token shortly before you know the current access token is about to expire, using the token's "exp (expiration time)" claim. That at least removes one API call - the call with the access token that causes a 401.